# Traversing and Replacing an Doubly-Linked List of Char values using a listIterator

Tags: java, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I need to traverse a Doubly-linked list of characters. I need to replace every captial 'Y' in my list with a '!' and after, traversing backwards, replace every 'M' with a ' ' in the same list iterator created. If yo need more context to the question I will add more, but for now thats the not-to-long explanation.

**My code so far:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    KWLinkedList<Character> list = new KWLinkedList<Character>() ;
    String linkString = "ZekqmDXJGfaos3MPaSl8p1La.9rXEt43a=Cn#Ds72Y";

    for(int i = 0;  i < linkString.length();i++)
    {
        list.add(linkString.charAt(i));
    }

    ListIterator myIterator = list.listIterator(0) ;

    int i = 0;
    while(!myIterator.hasNext())
    {


        myIterator.next();
        if(myIterator.equals('Y'))
        {
            list.set(list.get(i), 'Y' );
            i = list.get(0);
        }
        if(myIterator.equals('M'))
        {
            list.set(list.get(i - 1), ' ');

        }
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println(list.toString()); // just to see what comes out
```

Comment: So what is the problem you faced? `KWLinkedList` is it a usual `LinkedList`?

Comment: `myIterator.equals('Y')` compares list iterator itself not element to which iterator points with Character

Comment: @Maxim My iterator just doesnt work. It gets skipped passed every time.

Comment: @Ivan okay so I just need to compare the list items then

Comment: 1) `while(!myIterator.hasNext())` means the loop is never entered, since `hasNext()` is true, so `! hasNext()` is false. Remove the *not* operator. --- 2) Calling `myIterator.next()` returns the next value, so you need to assign it to a variable, so you can use that variable on the following statements. --- 3) What is the point of `i = list.get(0);`? --- 4) You have an updatable iterator, so use it. --- 5) `ListIterator` is a *raw* generic. Do not use *raw* generics.

Comment: And when you compare do it as `myIterator.next().equals('Y')`

Comment: @Andreas right. I made the change before but it still ignores the loop regardless, like what Ivan said, I need to find a way to somehow find the element which the iterator points to, not the iterator itself.

Comment: @Isuru How come it would be next() instead of hasNext() ?

Comment: And you traverse only forward. You need second `while` to traverse backward to replace `M`, according to the task description

Comment: *"and after, traversing backwards"* I see no attempt at traversing backwards.

Comment: `hasNext()` function returns a boolean, whether iterator has a value or not. But `next()` method returns the value pointed by the iterator.

Comment: @Andreas Yea, there was no attempt made. I needed direction before I started on it. and I can just store that value I get from myIterator.get() into my local variable and just use that while traversing right?

Comment: @EOxJ For what you need, you should never call `get()`. The iterator returns the value of the next/previous element as you iterate, so why would you need to call `get()` to get the value you already have?

Comment: @Andreas okay thanks, ill try something out, and ill let you know if it blows up on me.

Comment: @Isuru thanks ill give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined your attempt with Andreas solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Character> list = new LinkedList<>();
    String linkString = "ZekqmDXJGfaos3MPaSl8p1La.9rXEt43a=Cn#Ds72Y";

    for (int i = 0; i < linkString.length(); i++) {
        list.add(linkString.charAt(i));
    }

    ListIterator<Character> myIterator = list.listIterator(0);

    while (myIterator.hasNext()) {
        char c =  myIterator.next();
        if (c == 'Y') {
            myIterator.set('!');
        }
    }
    while (myIterator.hasPrevious()) {
        char c = myIterator.previous();
        if (c == 'M') {
            myIterator.set(' ');
        }
    }

    System.out.println(list.toString()); // just to see what comes out
}
```

output looks like below
[Z, e, k, q, m, D, X, J, G, f, a, o, s, 3,  , P, a, S, l, 8, p, 1, L, a, ., 9, r, X, E, t, 4, 3, a, =, C, n, #, D, s, 7, 2, !]

Comment: Don't use a *raw* `ListIterator`. This also eliminates the need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

To use a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) to traverse forward and replace some items, using the [`set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set-E-) method:

```
ListIterator<Character> iter = list.listIterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    char c = iter.next(); // gets next value and auto-unboxes the Character to a char
    if (c == 'A')         // primitives are compared using `==`
        iter.set('B');    // auto-boxes the char literal to a Character and replaces the value
}
```

At this point, the iterator is at the end of the list, so you can use it to traverse backwards:

```
while (iter.hasPrevious()) {
    char c = iter.previous(); // gets previous value, ie. moves backwards
    if (c == 'C')
        iter.set('D');
}
```